# Normal subgroup of $S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

For the subgroup $N$ of $S_3$, $N = \{(1),(123),(132)\}$, I calculate that $(13)N = \{(13),(123),(23)\}$ and $N(13) = \{(13),(23),(12)\}$. Shouldn't this show that $N$ is not a normal subgroup, as opposed to what's printed here?

[image]

Comment: something is wrong for your coset $(13)N$

Comment: Also, you can show that if a group has cardinality $2n$, then every subgroup of order $n$ is automatically normal. $N$ has 3 elements, $S_3$ has six.

Comment: You calculated wrongly! $(123)\notin(13)N$. Any subgroup of index 2 has to be normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation of $(13)N$ is wrong. The $(123)$ should be $(12)$. One way to check this is that every permutation in $N$ is even, so the coset should consist only of odd permutations.

Comment: Thanks. I've just realized!